# 14.04 Serious Internet Problems

Tags: 14.04, networking, atheros

For the past two months (or more), after installing Ubuntu 14.04 from an old disk, I have been having serious Internet problems. My Internet connection drops every single day and I cant find a solution to it.

Sometimes when I'm lucky, my Internet lasts for an a few hours. However, most of the time, my Internet connection just randomly drops and the only way to fix it is to restart.

Right before the connection drops, my mouse becomes really laggy. After about 10-30 minutes, I always have to restart my laptop about twice to fix it. Sometimes, like today, my connection drops around every 2-5 minutes. As I was posting this, I had to restart about 7-9 times (not exaggerated at all!) because each time I would restart, the connection would get lost on lockscreen or get lost after entering my password, about 2-5 minutes later.

Here is my Networks card-->

> 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
>   Kernel driver in use: ath9k

How can I fix my connection problem?

It has become very annoying and a pain to deal with. I cant get anything done and it just wastes a lot of time.

I have already tried using a proprietary driver but when I go to Additional Drivers, there is no driver avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

I have possibly identical network hardware - AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) Qualcomm Atheros, and kernel driver ath9k. You did not indicate whether you were using a wired or wireless connection. (I am using a wireless connection.) My symptoms are not identical with yours, but you may want to hear this...

When I upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 (Unity desktop) I experienced deteriorating DNS performance over a period of weeks until I could only reach my Gmail account, or view web pages cached on Google. I researched the confusing changes in DNS resolution configuration which apparently began with Ubuntu 12.04. These changes involve critical symbolic file links. I reasoned that repeated upgrades may have caused some link in my network setup to be broken during the upgrade, and experimentally deleted my wi-fi connection, restarted, and allowed the session to re-detect my network connection. My network reappeared, I selected it as default, and accepted the default settings, and my network connectivity was restored with DNS resolution working normally once again.

I cannot say I understand precisely what was wrong, but then it's often the case that mysterious problems are solved by a fresh install. In this case simply refreshing your network setup may be something to try. Your network should be re-detected on restart, and no harm done to it. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try. btw I'm using a wireless connection.